# Regex for string starting with doueble quote and ending with [

Tags: json, regex, ansible

I have to update dictionary with new value for existing key in a JSON file.
I need no write new line after existing string using regex

Current file:

```
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "desc": "Service aaa",
    "boss":"user@company.de",
    "email": [
        "user@company.de"
    ],
```

desired file:

```
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "desc": "Service aaa",
    "boss":"user@company.de",
    "email": [
        "user@company.de"
        "another_user@company.de"
    ]
```

I have this ansible lineinfile module playbook, but I struggle with decent regex. Everything I try just adds new line in the very end of file.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: insert line
    lineinfile:
     path: /home/file.json
     state: present
     insertafter:  " ^ "email": [ "
     line: 'another_user@company.de'
```

How should I write correct regex in this case to write line after the string "email": [  ?

Comment: JSON format is complex enough so that using regex is not recommended for it. Use proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say current file is aa.txt as follows

```
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "desc": "Service aaa",
    "boss":"user@company.de",
    "email": [
        "user@company.de"
    ],
```

Use sed command

```
sed '/"email.*\[/!{p;d;};n;a new line' aa.txt
```

### Output

```
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "desc": "Service aaa",
    "boss":"user@company.de",
    "email": [
        "user@company.de"
new line
    ],
```

Alternatively use AWK

```
awk '1;/"email.*\[/{c=2}c&&!--c{print "new text"}' aa.txt
```

### Output

```
{
    "id": "aaaa",
    "desc": "Service aaa",
    "boss":"user@company.de",
    "email": [
        "user@company.de"
new line
    ],
```

Comment: Now i get new line after every curly bracket in json file:
```
{

    "aaaa": "aaaa",
    "cccc": "ddd",
    "eee": "fff",
    "email": [
        "ggg",
new line
        "ggg"
    ],
    "hhh": [],
    "ii": "uu",
new line
    "ii": "uu",
    "kk": [
        {
new line
```

Answer (score 0):

quick comment :

[`JSON`](https://json.org) spec mandates an `ASCII` comma (`","`) between values of arrays (plus your choice of whitespace(s)), so to make the proposed solutions compliant, they would have to resemble this instead

—— (snippet directly from `jq`):

```
{
  "id": "aaaa",
  "desc": "Service aaa",
  "boss": "user@company.de",
  "email": [
    "user@company.de",
    "newline"
  ]
}
```